# Python Webscraping API dynamic parameter values

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to search restaurants by location and get their menus, address etc. When I opened the site manually, I saw that the data was available via 2 requests. 1 for the location search, second for the `menuId`. Since, the api url takes Latitude and Longitude as input for search, I added a code for that. However, I don't know what to do with the `trackingId` part. How to get this, if at all possible for subsequent searches. Also, I am thinking there is no way to know which restaurant has which `menuID` which is also needed in the api url. So, is this possible with `requests` alone? Do I need to use something else entirely or a combination?. Thanks very much in advance.

```
import time

import requests
import urllib.parse

print("Welcome to Restaurant Search")
time.sleep(1)
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'}
address = input("Enter the City name :")
lat_long_url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/' + urllib.parse.quote(address) +'?format=json'
lat_long = requests.get(url=lat_long_url, headers=headers).json()
time.sleep(3)
name = input("Enter the name of the Restaurant :")
search_url = f'https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/restaurants/search/v2_2?lat={lat_long[0]["lat"]}&lng={lat_long[0]["long"]}&trackingId=ebaedb8a-d86d-2e0b-69c8-4a3643e7a397&str={name}&sld=false&non_partner_search=false'
rest_url = f'https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/menu/v4/full?lat={lat_long[0]["lat"]}&lng={lat_long[0]["lon"]}&menuId=41100'(This)
n = False

info = requests.get(search_url).json()
print(info)
restaurant = info["data"]['restaurants']
for v in restaurant:
    restaurant_name = [v['restaurants']]
    for v in restaurant_name:

        for k in v:
            if not n:
                print("Restaurant Name: {}".format(k['name']))
                print("City: {}".format(k['city']))
                print("Area: {}".format(k['area']))
                print("Ratings: {}".format(k['avgRating']))
                n = True
```

**Edit** I tried it with the same `trackingID`. It works as of now, no idea if it will be an issue in the future. However, still no way to figure out the `menuID` part.

**INFO** ..when I send a request to `https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/menu/v4/full?` It says it needs a `slug` or a `menuId`. The original response has a `slug like so..''slugs': {'restaurant': 'pebble-street-new-friends-colony-lajpat-nagar', 'city': 'delhi'}' . So, I guess I will try to see how to put this in the request.cannot find out how as of now